# User name availability

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making a sign up form. It has a textbox called `UserName`. I want to check username availability on clicking a button. I am using asp.net MVC4. On clicking button I called the following function. It returns successfully if username is already in database but it does not return if username is not in database. It stops while executing query. This is my function code. I want to return false if username is not available.

```
public JsonResult CheckUserName()
{
    string userName = Request["UserName"];

    var cx = new PostAdPage.Models.mydbEntities3();

    // Stops at this line if username is not available
    var u = cx.signups.First(x => x.username.Equals(userName));    

    if (u.username.Equals(userName))
    {
        return this.Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return this.Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Always use try catch when you are facing any exceptions. As username is not found it is returning null exception. Use try catch and return false in the exception.
P.S use proper variable names so that a layman like me can understand.

Edited: Yes, we should use try catch exception handling only for exceptional cases. My point was that at first if you don't know which exception is occurring you should use this to find out the type of exception and then handle accordingly.

Comment: I would recommend not doing this, use exceptions only for exceptional cases, having a username not found is not exceptional, it's expected to happen.

Comment: -1, you should rarely catch exceptions. This is in fact a case where you should absolutely never consider using an exception under any circumstances ever (ever).

Answer (score 6):

The call to [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535183.aspx) throws an exception when no result is found, so I guess that is why it stops executing in your case.

You should call [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301896.aspx) instead, which returns null if there is no matching username.

```
var u = cx.signups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.username.Equals(userName));

if (u != null) //Found
    return this.Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
else //Not found
    return this.Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: While `FirstOrDefault` will definitely work, I believe `SingleOrDefault` is semantically more correct.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `SingleOrDefault()` instead of `First()`.

When you use `First()`-

- it returns the first element of a sequence that satisfies a specified condition.
- if the condition doesn't match anything and hence, it does throw an exception.

When you use `SingleOrDefault()` -

- as the name suggests returns a single, specific element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements.
- The default value is `null` in this case.
- This method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.

You can further check the null value and if null , then return appropriate response.
So, your method will look like this:

```
public JsonResult CheckUserName()
{
    string userName = Request["UserName"];

    var cx = new PostAdPage.Models.mydbEntities3();

    // Check unique unsername
    var u = cx.signups.SingleOrDefault(x => x.username.Equals(userName));    

    if (u != null)
    {
        return this.Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return this.Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

In one of the answer, `FirstOrDefault()` is used to check for username availability.

- **Note that** The `FirstOrDefault` method does not provide a way to specify the default value to return if source is empty [[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301896.aspx).
- In case, if you have two same usernames in the database, it will return the first between them. Registration is sensitive issue related to security. So, `SingleOrDefault()` is semantically more appropriate to use in this context.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing but more briefly:

```
public JsonResult CheckUserName()
{
    string userName = Request["UserName"];

    var cx = new PostAdPage.Models.mydbEntities3();

    // Check unique unsername
    var isUunique = cx.signups.Any(x => x.username.Equals(userName));    

    return Json(isUunique, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```